# Do Curtmola et al.'s IND-CKA1/2 security definitions protect against search pattern leakage?

Tags: security-definition, searchable-encryption

In the 
[article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/210.pdf) *Searchable Symmetric Encryption:
Improved Definitions and Efficient Constructions*, Curtmola et al. propose adaptive and non-adaptive (indistinguishability and simulator-based) security definitions for searchable encryption schemes, conventionally called IND-CKA1 and IND-CKA2.

**My question is: Do the IND-CKA1/2 security definitions guarantee that the search pattern is not leaked (i.e., that an attacker can not distinguish whether two issued trapdoors are generated with the same keywords)?**

In their article, they mention that

> [...] the  security  notion  achieved  for SSE is that nothing is leaked beyond the access pattern and the search pattern [...]

Further, in their [article](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11483856.pdf), Bösch et al. state that

> Curtmola et al. review existing security definitions for searchable encryption and propose new indistinguishability and simulation-based definitions that address the shortcomings of the existing
>   definitions. At the same time they loosen the character of SSE by allowing the
>   leakage  of  a  user's  search  pattern.

So it seems pretty obvious that the definition should not guarantee search pattern hiding. Nevertheless, taking a look at the IND-CKA2 definition:

$\mathbf{\mathrm{Ind}}^{*}_{\mathrm{SSE},\mathcal{A}}(k)
\\
\;K\leftarrow \mathrm{Gen}(1^k)\\
\;b\overset{\$}{\leftarrow}\{0,1\}\\
\;(\mathrm{st}_{\mathcal{A}},\mathbf{D}_{0},\mathbf{D}_{1})\leftarrow\mathcal{A}_{0}(1^k)\\
\;(I_{b},\mathbf{c}_{b})\leftarrow\mathrm{Enc}_{K}(\mathbf{D}_{b})\\
\;(\mathrm{st}_{\mathcal{A}},w_{0,1},w_{1,1})\leftarrow\mathcal{A}_{1}(\mathrm{st}_\mathcal{A},I_{b})\\
\;t_{b,1}\leftarrow\mathrm{Trpdr}_{K}(w_{b,1})\\
\;\mbox{for }2\le i\le q,\\
\quad(\mathrm{st}_{\mathcal{A}},w_{0,i},w_{1,i})\leftarrow\mathcal{A}_{i}(\mathrm{st}_{\mathcal{A}},I_{b},c_{b},t_{b,1},\ldots,t_{b,i-1})\\
\quad t_{b,i}\leftarrow\mathrm{Trpdr}_{K}(w_{b,i})\\
\;\mbox{let }\mathbf{t}_{b}=(t_{b,1},\ldots,t_{b,q})\\
\;b'\leftarrow \mathcal{A}_{q+1}(\mathrm{st}_{\mathcal{A}},I_{b},\mathbf{c}_{b},\mathbf{t}_{b})\\
\;\mbox{if }b'=b\mbox{, output }1\\
\;\mbox{otherwise output }0$

one sees that any algorithm able to distinguish whether two trapdoors encode the same words or not directly breaks IND-CKA2, which would mean that IND-CKA2 protects against search pattern leakage.

For instance, and very informally, in the first trapdoor query $\mathcal{A}$ can set $w_{0,1}=w_{1,1}=w_{1}$ for some fixed $w_{1}$ and receive $t_{b,1}=\mathrm{Trpdr}_{K}(w_{1})$. In the second query, it can issue $w_{0,2}=w_{1}$ and $w_{1,2}\neq w_{1}$. Then $t_{b,2}$ either encodes $w_{1}$ or some other word, and $\mathcal{A}$ can guess $b$ by guessing whether $t_{b,1}$ and $t_{b,2}$ encode the same word ($b=0$) or not ($b=1$). Continuing in this fashion, since $\mathcal{A}$ breaks the "search pattern challenge", $\mathcal{A}$ has a non-negligible advantage in distinguishing $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $\tau(\mathbf{D}_{0}, w_{0,1},\ldots,w_{0,q})=\tau(\mathbf{D}_{1}, w_{1,1},\ldots,w_{1,q})$ rules out the possibility that $\mathcal{A}$ issues the keywords as I pointed in the question, since the output of $\tau$ includes the search pattern matrix defined in page 9. This has the effect of weakening the definition to allow search pattern leakage.

As a note, the stronger definition in Shen et al.'s [1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-00457-5_27) does not include a restriction of this type, and so it captures the search pattern protection property.

[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-00457-5_27) Shen, Emily, Elaine Shi, and Brent Waters. “[Predicate Privacy in Encryption Systems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-00457-5_27).” In Theory of Cryptography, edited by Omer Reingold, 5444:457–73. Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2009.